# What is 寒ぶ寒ぶ? (in following sentence)

Tags: meaning, dialects, i-adjectives

> まず癪に障るのは、同じ人間とは思えぬその鋼のごとき肉体であった。目方はおよそ喜惣次の倍はあろうか。「おお、**寒ぶ寒ぶ**」と胴間声を張り上げながら湯舟に躍りこめば、湯の半分くらいが溢れ出る騒ぎであった。

Google/dictionary search gave me nothing... Is it same as e.g. [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w4sowzielCs)?

Answer (score 5):

It's 「おお、さぶさぶ」, which is semantically the same as 「おお、寒い、寒い」.

- [さぶい](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/89048/meaning/m0u/) is a dialectal variation of さむい. 寒【さ】ぶい is not the standard kun-yomi of this kanji, but some people use it.
- い after さぶ is omitted here [because it's an exclamation](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21418/5010).

Comment: I always assumed it was a general sound change like さみしい ↔ さびしい and not a dialectal variation. Are you saying there are some dialects that prefer さぶい over さむい (and could you give some examples)?

Comment: Here's [the map by 国立国語研究所](http://www2.ninjal.ac.jp/hogen/dp/gaj-pdf/gaj-pdf_index.html) (第6集第321-326図), although it may be too detailed. Apparently, さぶい is found in most part of Japan, but there are places where one is clearly dominant than the other. From my personal experience I feel さぶい is more prevalent in Osaka than Tokyo, but I may be wrong.

Comment: さぶ is the sound that happens when one tries to say さむ while their nose is cold with frost.

Comment: @Earthliŋ I think it's both :-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm from Ohita, Kyushu. In Ohita, we exclaim "オー、[寒]{さ}ぶ、[寒]{さ}ぶ" instead of "[寒々]{さむさむ}," when we go out of door, are blown with chilly wind, or get into the bathroom in winter time.

I don't know about other areas, but「おお、寒ぶ寒ぶ」is quite a common saying in Kyushu area.